# Reacts version of ngForm

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs, angularjs-ng-form

I have been playing around with React lately and really like it but I'm missing a couple of things that I'm used to having in other frameworks. The main one of these in ngForm from angular, angular uses this to provide really simple form validation. Checking if a form in valid is as simple as vm.myForm.$valid.

In react I find myself writing a ton of boilerplate to basically dup what I had in ngForm. I was wondering if there was a go to plugin for form validation and if not there is a preferred way the community do validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly recommend [formsy-react](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/), with this library, you can easily custom all the validations and error messages.

Then your code would be,

```
 import Formsy from 'formsy-react';

  const MyAppForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
      return {
        canSubmit: false
      }
    },
    enableButton() {
      this.setState({
        canSubmit: true
      });
    },
    disableButton() {
      this.setState({
        canSubmit: false
      });
    },
    submit(model) {
      someDep.saveEmail(model.email);
    },
    render() {
      return (
        <Formsy.Form onValidSubmit={this.submit} onValid={this.enableButton} onInvalid={this.disableButton}>
          <MyOwnInput name="email" validations="isEmail" validationError="This is not a valid email" required/>
          <button type="submit" disabled={!this.state.canSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </Formsy.Form>
      );
    }
  });
```

Here are [some examples](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/tree/master/examples) and [API documents](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/blob/master/API.md).